# web services and custom soap handlers

Tags: java, service, web

I want to know if we can we publish web services just with the help of wsdd file? I have a custom made wsdd file and if i deploy it in tomcat then my web services will be published.

I want to know how it works without wsdl file ? then i want to know how to provide our own custom soap handlers instead of axis handlers .anyone who has worked on this.

Comment: Don't panic and lose control.

Answer (score 0):

Well with Axis (as well as CXF) you can either have your wsdd/wsdl file and from there the framework will generate the necessary mapped classes, needing only for you to implement the actual business logic (contract first), or you can create your business logic classes and your data model classes, annotate them, and from there the framework will autogenerate the wsdd and/or wsdl file (contract last):

http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3745701/Enterprise-Java-Contract-First-vs-Contract-Last-Web-Services.htm